# Complexity equal point of two sort alghorithms

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math

Say I have two sorting algorithm with the following complexities:
Insert-Sort with

> 8*n^2

and Merge-Sort with

> 64*n*lgn (**binary base!**)

Starting on which n the merge-sort will be faster then the insert-sort?
Thanks.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8+*+n^2+%3C+64+*+n+lg%28n%29

Comment: @Tacet make it an answer, you deserve reputations.

Comment: Also this belongs to math.stackexchange.com more than here, because it is a complex mathematics problem.

Comment: The complexity formulas completely ignore constant multipliers and lower-order terms, which are essential in a real-world comparison. The only way to know for sure is to write both sets of code and benchmark with different data sets.

Comment: And here's the analytic solution on math.stackexchange: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616880/solving-8n2-64-n-logn

Comment: @arunmoezhi: Wow, can't believe this has an exact duplicate. I'd have voted for off-topic otherwise :-)

Comment: The numbers match :)

Comment: I've just edited the question. The log base is 2. So the questions are not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't hard problem. The question is, for which `n` expression `64*n*lgn` is smaller than `8*n^2`. To solve this problem you can use one of available mathematical tools (for example [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/)). For your problem, look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8%20*%20n%5E2%20%3C%2064%20*%20n%20lg(n)).

Also, if you want, you can compute the value of these expressions for all n until you find sought value. Of course, I suggest write the program to that.

The last possibility is to calculate it manually, if you know math enough. This requires extensive calculations (example, for logarithm with base 2):

[image]
and
[image]

give us [image]

Now you can leave it in this form, and direct to [symbolic computation-calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E(n/8)%20%3E%20n). From explanation form, you can read that n is bigger than 43. However it's problem to [another site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616880/solving-8n2-64-n-logn) (link from @Anonymous comment, thx).

Comment: Thank you so much @Tacet. Is there a way to manually solve the 2^(n/8)=n equation?

Comment: Not at all. You can estimate result, and check nearby numbers. For more details you should read about Omega function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function